# Strange behavior with SwiftUI navigation

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I've migrated an iOS app with VIPER architecture and XIBs to SwiftUI. It have to support iOS 14 (which I know is a bit low for the best SwiftUI performance).

I'm having problems with this navigation:

SettingsView > ProfileView > EditProfileView.
When user jumps from a form field to the next in the EditProfileView, ProfileView is refreshed (yes, ProfileView, the parent view), it creates again EditProfileView and this cleans my form.

I've tested this:

SettingsView > EditProfileView
And this is working OK.

This is the code of this navigation (it's modified to the key parts just to be clearer).
EDIT: Following jnpdx advise, I've refactored the code to remove the AnyView uses and use instead the specific Views. This code already includes this refactor, although my problem keeps happening.

SettingsView

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var observedModel: SettingsViewAdapter
    
    init(observedModel: SettingsViewAdapter) {
        self.observedModel = observedModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                
                VStack {

                    NavigationLink(destination: ProfileRouter().swiftUIView
                        .navigationBarHidden(true),
                                   isActive: $observedModel.hasToGoToEdition) {
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    .hidden()
        ...
    }
}
```

ProfileRouter

```
class ProfileRouter: NSObject {
    
    public var swiftUIView: ProfileView

    @objc override init() {
        
        let viewAdapter = ProfileViewAdapter()
        let presenter: ProfileRouterToPresenterProtocol &
                       ProfileViewToPresenterProtocol &
                       ProfileInteractorToPresenterProtocol = ProfilePresenter()
        let interactor: ProfileRouterToInteractorProtocol &
                        ProfilePresenterToInteractorProtocol &
                        ProfileRepositoryToInteractorProtocol = ProfileInteractor()
        let repository: ProfileRouterToRepositoryProtocol &
                        ProfileInteractorToRepositoryProtocol = ProfileRepository()

        viewAdapter.set(presenter: presenter)
        presenter.set(view: viewAdapter, interactor: interactor)
        interactor.set(presenter: presenter, repository: repository)
        repository.set(interactor: interactor)
        self.swiftUIView = viewAdapter.swiftUIView
    }
    
}
```

ProfileViewAdapter

```
class ProfileViewAdapter: ObservableObject {
    
    lazy var swiftUIView: ProfileView = {
            ProfileView(observedModel: self)
    }()
    
    var presenter: ProfileViewToPresenterProtocol?

    @Published var hasToGoToEdition: Bool = false

    init() {}
}
```

ProfileView

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var observedModel: ProfileViewAdapter
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    init(observedModel: ProfileViewAdapter) {
        self.observedModel = observedModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditProfileRouter().swiftUIView
                                                                            .navigationBarHidden(true),
                                   isActive: $observedModel.hasToGoToEdition) {
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    .hidden()
        ...
    }
}
```

EditProfileRouter

```
class EditProfileRouter: NSObject {
    
    public var swiftUIView: EditProfileView

    @objc override init() {
        
        let viewAdapter = EditProfileViewAdapter()
        let presenter: ProfileRouterToPresenterProtocol &
                       ProfileViewToPresenterProtocol &
                       ProfileInteractorToPresenterProtocol = ProfilePresenter()
        let interactor: ProfileRouterToInteractorProtocol &
                        ProfilePresenterToInteractorProtocol &
                        ProfileRepositoryToInteractorProtocol = ProfileInteractor()
        let repository: ProfileRouterToRepositoryProtocol &
                        ProfileInteractorToRepositoryProtocol = ProfileRepository()

        viewAdapter.set(presenter: presenter)
        presenter.set(view: viewAdapter, interactor: interactor)
        interactor.set(presenter: presenter, repository: repository)
        repository.set(interactor: interactor)
        self.swiftUIView = viewAdapter.swiftUIView
    }
}
```

EditProfileViewAdapter

```
class EditProfileActionViewAdapter: ObservableObject {
    
    lazy var swiftUIView: EditProfileView = {
        EditProfileView(observedModel: self)
    }()
    
    var presenter: ProfileViewToPresenterProtocol?
    
    @Published var userName: String = ""

    init() {}
}

extension EditProfileViewAdapter: ProfileRouterToViewProtocol {
    
    func set(presenter: ProfileViewToPresenterProtocol) {
        self.presenter = presenter
    }
}

extension EditProfileViewAdapter: ProfilePresenterToViewProtocol {
    
    func showProfile(profile: Profile) {

        self.userName = profile.getUsername()
    }
}
```

EditProfileView

```
struct EditProfileView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var observedModel: EditProfileActionViewAdapter
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State var fieldFocus = [false, false, false, false, false]

    init(observedModel: EditProfileViewAdapter) {
        
        self.observedModel = observedModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                
                VStack {

                    CustomNavigationBar(title: "EDIT_PROFILE".localized,
                                        hasBack: true,
                                        backAction: {
                                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                                        })
                                            
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                            
                                 CustomTextField(inputText: $observedModel.userEmail,
                                                focusable: $fieldFocus,
                                                tag: 0,
                                                isSuccess: observedModel.emailErrorMessage?.isEmpty,
                                                returnKeyType: .next,
                                                maxChars: FORM_REGISTER_FIELD_CHAR_MAX,
                                                allowedChars: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890@._%+-")
                                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 25)
                                    .padding(.bottom, hasEmailError ? 16 : 34)
            ...
            }
            .onAppear {
                 observedModel.presenter?.getProfile()
            }
    }
```

As I commented, the user focus on userEmail field (everything is OK), this clicks on Next key on keyboard, ProfileView (¡?) is refreshed, then it builds again EditProfileRouter, this builds again EditProfileViewAdapter, and the view shows every field empty.
When this happens (EditProfileViewAdapter is built again), EditProfileView doesn't call onAppear.

And a last clue: When this error happens, if I click back from EditProfileView, ProfileView is shown, then if I click again on EditProfile, EditProfileView is shown and everything works fine, I can fill the form, jump from a field to the next...the form is shown correctly. It's like the presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() fixed the problem...

What am i doing wrong with this navigation? Would you need another piece of code to see what's happening?

EDIT 2: I've found out another thing, it seems that the problem is due to this line:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
```

Both ProfileView and EditProfileView have this line of code and it seems that @Environment(.presentationMode) is "shared" between them.
If I remove @Environment(.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding from ProfileView, EditProfileView and its form works perfectly (but of course, I cannnot do presentationMode.dismiss() in ProfileView.
So my doubt now is, am I using well presentationMode? How should I use it with a flow like View1 > View2 > ... > ViewN?

Comment: Too much code to dig through and try, but I'm immediately suspicious of the `AnyView` usage -- this will break identity. Watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC for information on why.

Comment: This sounded promising, but I've just refactored my code to remove every AnyView use and use instead the specific view in every case, and the same problem keeps happening.

Comment: SwiftUI works differently, instead presenting and then using onAppear to get the data you should already have the data prepared beforehand and SwiftUI will present the necessary UI automatically for you. So you can remove your presenter code and your view model objects too and just use the View struct.